# How to headless update and export to pdf with libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm perfectly able to export to pdf from the writer GUI after searching and replacing a word via script (unzip odt;sed xml;zip odt).

However exporting via the commandline exports the **old** word instead of the new: `lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf textfile.odt`

How can I export via commandline?

---

#### How to reproduce:

1. Create a new calc file
2. Write **foo** into cell `A1`
3. Save the calc file as `/tmp/calc.ods`
4. Create a new writer file
5. Embed `/tmp/calc.ods` as linked object into the writer file: `Insert > OLE Object > OLE Object > Create from file > Check Link to file`
6. Save the writer file as `/tmp/result.odt`

Replace `foo` in the calc file with `bar` using this shell script:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir bla
cd bla
unzip ../calc.ods # Unpack the calc file to edit
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' content.xml #Replace foo with bar
zip -r ../calc.ods . # Pack the calc file back
```

Now export the writer file to pdf and expect to see the new value (bar) in `result.pdf`:

```
lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf /tmp/result.odt
```

Why does the exported pdf still show the old value (foo)?

Comment: Add the script to your question.

Comment: The question is  **if** any script solves the problem

Comment: Without the script we can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Edit: soffice/lowriter lacks the quiet-update option, thus install unoconv. apt install unoconv then unoconv -v --unsafe-quiet-update your-file-with-linked-object.odt

Comment: Provide detail on how you link/embed the file. It appears that the way you work, a copy embedded in the .odt file is used during conversion to PDF.

Comment: @Olivetti That's the answer, thank you